# jQuery $(...).empty().append(...) slows down whole page after several executions

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm using `$('#...').empty().append(html)`-like construction to update  content on AJAX success.
After 5-6 requests whole page goes slower and slower with each request (:hover takes more time to appear, JS slows down, etc.). This happens in any browser. The more content is loaded, the faster slowdown happens.

I think I'm missing some cleanup somewhere.
Any advice?

Code:

```
query = function (uri, data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        cache: false,   
        data: data,
        success: processResponse,
        method: data?'POST':'GET',
    });
    return false;
}

processResponse = function (data) {
    $('#rightplaceholder').empty();
    $('#rightplaceholder').append(data);
}

$('#button').click( function () { query('/foo'); } );
```

I've also tried disabling all JS not directly related to loading this fragment - with no luck.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Do you really need to destroy and rebuild that entire section? It would be better if you can just update the existing DOM elements.

Comment: I've tried with 1.4.3 and 1.6.4, without difference.

Comment: I really need to reload whole block since it holds switchable pages, and user navigates between these with AJAX requests.

Comment: Why are you not caching the AJAX request? At least it would speed up things when you're not submitting data with the request; POST submissions shouldn't be cached regardless.

Comment: @mblase75 to be clear, it's Ajenti webadmin panel (ajenti.org). Pages are containing dynamic data that indeed *needs* to be reloaded on-click.

Comment: @Hardex Then you need to either stop using AJAX, or stop making AJAX requests until they're absolutely necessary. You are asking the browser to make huge changes to the DOM over and over again and slowdown in that case is inevitable.

Comment: Why should 5 requests of 80kb each affect performance so badly (on Core i7 CPU)? By the way, refreshing the page repairs the performance at once.

Comment: Sounds more like a memory leak to me. Does the Ajenti code have its own JavaScript that it runs? Does it bind handlers? Is there anything included in its API for removing itself from a page?

Comment: I had Twitter Bootstrap JS in use. Removing it fixed the problem.

Comment: [Alrighty.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757600/jquery-empty-append-slows-down-whole-page-after-several-executions/7757968#7757968)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a memory leak caused by whatever supplementary JavaScript you (or the data you're loading) is running.

Remove all unnecessary code, or when removing elements from the page that are added by other code, make sure you use their API to do so, so it can have a chance to clean up.

Answer (score 4):

Try using  `$('#rightplaceholder').html(data);` instead, combining two DOM manipulations into one.

Also: change `cache: false` to `true` to speed up multiple AJAX requests. If you're not submitting data, then there should be no reason not to cache the results.

Comment: Enabling cache (just a try) also didn't affect performance slowdown.

Answer (score 2):

In general jQuery functions have a <s>little</s> lot of overhead, and I'm guessing that the combination of your settings and usage create a memory leak / slowness somewhere in the system. So +1 for finding this.

If you're really just replacing html, you could use the native innerHTML property, [it is well supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html) and does what you're trying to do here. It is usually the best method for replacing larger amounts of html. And as mentioned, it's even better to prevent replacing html a lot.

Example:

```
$('#rightplaceholder').innerHTML = data;
```

Make sure to set .innerHTML after appending the DOM element to the page, should prevent memory leaks. So using it on an existing element should be fine.

Comment: *"jQuery functions have a little overhead..."* There's a lot of overhead to jQuery, especially when removing elements from the DOM. *"If you're really just replacing html, you could use the native innerHTML property..."* Noooo... That's a memory leak just waiting to happen. Oh, and your `.innerHTML` example is wrong.